# iOS App doesn't work in other language

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, localization

My iOS-App was first German and English. As it was just a fault, I removed the English localization. Somehow if I change the language in the iOS Simulator to english not it loads the old storyboard that doesn't even exist anymore. I cleaned the folder and there is now only a base storyboard. Although I cleaned the Project the App is still crashing after start (because it's loading an old storyboard of prior App version (I removed english localization in 1.1, and now in 1.2 it still loads the 1.0 storyboard).
This is really weird, how can I achieve that the App ALWAYS uses the same storyboard, no matter which language? I already removed the english localization!

Thanks very much!

Comment: Make sure you entirely remove the app from the simulator.

Comment: Yes I've already done this, and even Apple rejected the update because the app crashed in English, so it must be a different problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding based on a previous experience, if you are localizing an application you need to keep the English one. Because it will default to English if the device is not set in the language that you are supporting.
(Have you notice in the setting app how english is always the second choice and that you can't change the order like on the desktop to default to something else before english)
So if you are planning on supporting only 1 language remove all localization into your application. Because other wise it would default to a non-existing asset and crash.

That would be my best guest for a try.

---

Have you delete the application on your device after all those change and a clean up may be necessary. I've notice that file, (especially not code file) that get deleted have a tendency to lay around the executable.
And if you get file (1) `b.xml` and (2) `fr.lproj/b.xml` even if the device if in french the french one (2) won't get used. The system will see (1) first and think there is no localization for that file.

As for "losing" your German Xib. If you take a copy out of your `de.lproj` (and put that copy up a directory in the file system it should work)

Comment: okay I did this different now. I completely added English language Ssupport :) But one question: Why is localization not working with local html files loaded in a UIWebVIew? everything is english now but it still loads the german HTML file although I created both German and English localized files.